# Accessing external hard drive in python

Tags: python, macos

Ultimately I'm trying to read file details of a folder (named 'test') in an external hard drive (named 'toshiba') connected to a mac e.g. filename and size and output it to a text file. However, I'm wondering why the following piece of code doesn't output correctly?

```
import os

testdir = "/volumes/toshiba"
for folder in testdir:
    print folder
```

I'm expecting it to output all the folders on the hard drive including 'test', however it outputs

```
/
v
o
l
u
m
e
s
/
t
o
s
h
i
b
a
```

Comment: `os.listdir('/volumes/toshiba')`

Comment: You are iterating over string not the directory itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
testdir = "/volumes/toshiba"
for folder in testdir:
```

You define a string (a sequence of characters), then you iterate that. That sequence of characters. And of course, when you print a sequence of characters, what else should be printed but *a sequence of characters*?!

Instead, you want to **pass** that string to a command like `os.listdir()` which will return a list of "path like" objects representing the actual content of the designated file system entry.